# Interactively use screencapture for video on macos

Tags: macos, terminal

MacOS has a tool to interactively take a screenshot using `cmd+shift+4` (to capture a section of the screen), and a tool to record a section of the screen using `cmd+shift+5`. Using the `screencapture` tool, you can trigger the `cmd+shift+4` tool from the terminal using the `screencapture` CLI tool like this:

```
screencapture -i $FILENAME
```

However, when I try to open the interactive video like this:

```
screencapture -i -v $FILENAME
```

I get the following message:

```
screencapture: video not valid with -i
```

Is it possible to open that `cmd+shift+5` tool from the terminal? Is there a tool other than `screencapture` that handles this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to open that `cmd+shift+5` tool, you can use option `-iU`.

However, this isn't a perfect solution:

- **The file output location from the CLI is ignored.** File will be stored wherever the UI is set to save it to. Note that this option is sticky, but the output file is based on the current time, so it's not easy to locate it from your CLI call. *(sidenote: the `--help` documentation seems to have put this on the `-u` option when it really applies to the `-U` option)*
- No `ctrl+c` cancel; must use menu bar icon instead.
- `-V` (video length) option is not respected